# Управление данными в таблицах

Tags: excel, powerbi

коллеги!

Имеется таблица, подготовленная в экселе и залитая в power bi
В ней есть данные по месяцам

Необходимо сделать по ней такое отображение, чтобы в powerBi можно было как-то кнопками или срезами выбирать период - январь, январь-февраль

И в таблице отображался только столбец с данными за январь

Или 2 столбца подряд - за январь и февраль
Итд
Как можно это сделать?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно сделать отдельную таблицу с датами и названием месяца, потом связать с этой таблице предыдущую, а из созданной таблицы столбец с названием месяца подтянуть в фильтр, лучше OKVIZ. Я бы предложил отображать информацию не в табличном виде а в виде горизонтальной диаграммы, так нагляднее, в цифры не нужно всматриваться.